# Don't know the right way on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am going to make a website and before that I am going to make a database table. The problem is how to do it correctly. Sorry, but I am new to PHP and Mysql. I only have a definite number of categories, so this is my DB view:

```
--------------------
Video_name   Varchar
Video_loc    Varchar
cat1         Boolean
cat2         Boolean
cat3         Boolean
cat4         Boolean
cat5         Boolean
cat6         Boolean
cat7         Boolean
--------------------
```

I kept it like this because 1 video might belong to 2 or more categories. But it will take a lot of space in long term. If a video belongs to cat2 & cat5 then the boolean will have the value "1". But others will also have the value "0" and this is a waste of space.

How can I do it the right way? BTW I have seen Wordpress, it gives the categories a unique ID then on the main table it specifies multiple ids for multiple categories like e.g.: it keeps it like:

```
-----------------------
id | title | category |

1  | Lorem | 2,4,8,16 |
2  | Epsum | 2,9,8,20 |
3  | Losum | 2,4,9,5  |
4  | Eprum | 2,10,8,1 |
-----------------------
```

I don't get how it did it like that. Can anyone tell me how to do it like this or any better idea than mine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally it is a "no no" to store structured data within a single column in a table. The Wordpress example does exactly that; it stores a comma separated list of categories in the category column. For that reason I would not recommend using that schema.

The "right" way to do this is to have a table for videos and another table for categories. The relationship between videos and categories is managed by a third table which maps the video to a category and vice versa. There will be multiple entries in this video-to-category table - one for each category that a video can be assigned. Something like this:

```
table: video
----------------
id       int
name     varchar
location varchar
----------------

table: category
----------------
id       int
name     varchar
----------------

table: video_category
---------------------
video_id          int
category_id       int
---------------------
```

Another way would be to use a [bit field](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-field-literals.html) for the categories. Your video table would then have just a single column for all categories with bits set to 1 for those categories to which the video belongs, and 0 for those that it does not. This is an option if storage space is very important to you, however, it is less flexible than using 3 tables, and I recommend the latter approach.

Comment: Using the associative table *is* the right way to normalize a relational database. I'd recommend against the bit-field because it might make direct interaction with the database by a user (e.g. OP) more difficult, requiring interpretation of video categories to be done programatically by extracting the relevant bits from the field. It would also be more of an issue to remember what each bit position meant, and increase the chances of introducing errors into the code, etc.

Comment: Ok got it !! I would manage 3 tables. But when I add the data to the fields with PHP I would have a form with which I would add name and location, and for each category I would have a checkbox. I would tick all the categories which it would belong to. I am confused how would I do that, because when I insert values to video table it will autoincrease the id value, then I wont be knowing in advance what id is the video belonging to so i cant fill the category and video_category table

Comment: Should I use "foreach" loop to add values to the video_categories table??

Comment: Generally you'll create your video and then add associations to it after going back and editing it, you pointed out the obvious issue with doing it at the start, you don't know what a new videos ID will be.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to insert the video first, get its ID, and then populate the video_category table with one entry per category. The category table would already be populated so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: To populate the video_category table with one entry per category, should I use foreach loop or any other method!!

Answer (score 1):

Generally you use a 3rd table with the relationship between the video and category. So you'd have a categories_videos table which has id, category_id, and video id

You can do joins to get all categories related to material, but this is more advanced MySQL. Either start reading the MySQL documentation or pickup a framework that helps you with all this and makes it easier, I always recommend Cakephp.

Comment: Thankyou!! I will look upon that but any idea about how wordpress do it? seperating categories with coma's (,) in a single table cell.

Comment: mhawke answered your question pretty well. If you have any questions that he did not answer fill free to ask and I'll comment to that answer.

Comment: Yes he answered well. But still have some questions. you may look to it under his comments! Thankyou